# Elasticsearch Heap Size

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ES cluster with 5 nodes. 1 acting as client node, 1 acting as master node and 3 as data nodes. 
I was using the default 1GB heap for each of these nodes. 
However, after getting Out Of Memory Exception, I increased the Heap to 16GB (I have machines upto 64GB RAM).
After this change in configuration, I have seen an increase in the documents (Number of documents and Total index size).
The inflow of data in both these scenarios has been constant.

Is there a possibility, that due to low memory, ES was not indexing all my data initially?
Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: Yes, very likely. Memory is needed at indexing time, as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you send HTTP request to ES to index one or more docs, the ES will respond with the action's result to you.

You should always check the response content to ensure your doc index was successful. Thus, if ES failed to index your doc request, you will know and can handle the situation appropriately.

Generally, if the CPU, Memory or Disk not meet ES's demand, it will reject your request, and give you an corresponding error message in the response.